# Laravel 5.8 Call to undefined relationship [sourceClient] on model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model WorkflowStep with a Polyphormic relation to TransportWorkflowStep and TransformworkflowStep

My transportWorkflowStep has an other relation to client.

When I do this in my code:

```php
    /** @var TransportWorkflowStep $workflowStepEntity */
    $workflowStepEntity = $workflowStep->entity;

    try {
        var_dump($workflowStepEntity->sourceClient);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        dd($exception);
    }
```

I get this error:

> Call to undefined relationship [sourceClient] on model [App\TransformWorkflowStep].

First weird thing is that I am working with TransportWorkflowStep when I dd($workflowstep) so I don’t know why he’s complaining about TransformWorkflowStep

**My WorkflowStep model:**

```php
    public function entity(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

**My TransportWorkflowStep model:**

```php
    public function workflowStep(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(WorkflowStep::class, 'entity');
    }

    public function sourceClient(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'source_id', 'id');
    }

    public function destinationClient(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'destination_id', 'id');
    }
```

**My TransformWorkflowStep model:**

```php
    public function workflowStep(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(WorkflowStep::class, 'entity');
    }
```

### EDIT

dump of $workflowStepEntity:

```
object(App\TransportWorkflowStep)[439]
  protected 'table' => string 'transport_workflow_steps' (length=24)
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'source_id' (length=9)
      1 => string 'destination_id' (length=14)
      2 => string 'source_options' (length=14)
      3 => string 'destination_options' (length=19)
  protected 'connection' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'keyType' => string 'int' (length=3)
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'withCount' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'exists' => boolean true
  public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '4d32e11c-6453-4f48-9419-7c5cbd647128' (length=36)
      'source_id' => string '8c826f52-a78c-4ef5-acf5-8e6fd59004a0' (length=36)
      'destination_id' => string '921f0d90-2fae-496e-9991-68128e87d6d5' (length=36)
      'source_options' => string 'source options' (length=14)
      'destination_options' => string 'destination options' (length=19)
      'created_at' => string '2019-07-04 11:17:35' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2019-07-12 08:39:58' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '4d32e11c-6453-4f48-9419-7c5cbd647128' (length=36)
      'source_id' => string '8c826f52-a78c-4ef5-acf5-8e6fd59004a0' (length=36)
      'destination_id' => string '921f0d90-2fae-496e-9991-68128e87d6d5' (length=36)
      'source_options' => string 'source options' (length=14)
      'destination_options' => string 'destination options' (length=19)
      'created_at' => string '2019-07-04 11:17:35' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2019-07-12 08:39:58' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
  protected 'changes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'casts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'deleted_at' (length=10)
  protected 'dateFormat' => null
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dispatchesEvents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'forceDeleting' => boolean false
```

### EDIT full code

WorkflowJob

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Workflow;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class WorkflowJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var Workflow
     */
    protected $workflowId;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     * @param string $workflowId
     */
    public function __construct(string $workflowId)
    {
        $this->workflowId = $workflowId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $this->execute(Workflow::find($this->workflowId));
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw $exception;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute the WorkflowJob.
     *
     * @param Workflow $workflow
     */
    private function execute(Workflow $workflow)
    {
        // start a new workflow instance
        $workflowInstance = $this->startWorkflowInstance($workflow);

        // start the first step
        StepJob::dispatch($workflowInstance, $workflow->workflowSteps->first()->order);
    }

    /**
     * Start a new WorflowInstance for a Workflow.
     *
     * @param Workflow $workflow
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    private function startWorkflowInstance(Workflow $workflow)
    {
        return $workflow->workflowInstances()->create([
            'started_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

StepJob:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Client;
use App\File;
use App\TransportWorkflowStep;
use App\WorkflowInstance;
use App\WorkflowStep;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class StepJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    const LOG_START = 'start';
    const LOG_END_SUCCESS = 'end';
    const LOG_END_FAIL = 'fail';

    /**
     * @var WorkflowInstance
     */
    private $workflowInstance;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $stepCount;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param WorkflowInstance $workflowInstance
     * @param int $order
     */
    public function __construct(WorkflowInstance $workflowInstance, int $order)
    {
        $this->workflowInstance = $workflowInstance;
        $this->stepCount = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->stepCount <= $this->workflowInstance->workflow->workflowSteps->count()) {
            /** @var WorkflowStep $workflowstep */
            $workflowstep = $this->workflowInstance->workflow->workflowSteps->where('order', $this->stepCount)->first();

            $workflowStepEntity = $workflowstep->entity;

            if ($workflowStepEntity instanceof TransportWorkflowStep) {
                /* @var TransportWorkflowStep $workflowStepEntity */
                try {
                    var_dump($workflowStepEntity->sourceClient);
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    dd($exception);
                }
                var_dump($workflowstep->entity->sourceClient);
            } else {
                $workflowstep->entity->transformer
            }

            StepJob::dispatch($this->workflowInstance, $this->stepCount + 1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

[workflow_steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC9FJ.png)

[transport_workflow_steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAT6j.png)

[transform_workflow_steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8C2U.png)

Comment: Are you sure it is morphing to a `TransportWorkflowStep` and not a `TransformWorkflowStep`. What is the output of `dd($workflowStepEntity);`?

Comment: Yes I dd'd $workflowStepEntity and it is a TransportWorkflowStep object

Comment: Where does the variable `$workflowStep` comes from? It seems like this model instance is bound to a `App\TransformWorkflowStep` instead of `App\TransportWorkflowStep`.

Comment: @Shizzen83 look at the relations I have a WorkflowStep model and a TransportWorkflowStep and a TransformWorkflowStep

Comment: You didn't understand my question, I asked about the `$workflowStep` variable in 1st snippet. You probably declared it before but we can't see it

Comment: yes it's a parameter in my method `WorkflowStep $workflowStep` that works great everything works great if I do `$workflowStep->entity`but as soon as i try to access sourceClient it crashes

Answer (score 0):

You message sais: `Call to undefined relationship [sourceClient] on model [App\TransformWorkflowStep].`

Your model definition(`TransformWorkflowStep`):

```
public function workflowStep(): MorphOne
{
    return $this->morphOne(WorkflowStep::class, 'entity');
}
```

Error message is correct, there is no sourceClient relationship on TransformWorkflowStep model. You should define it or stop using it like this ;)

EDIT:
Could you try to do this:

```
foreach($workflowStepCollection as $workflowStep)
{
    dump($workflowStep->entity);
    try
    {
        $x = $workflowStep->sourceClient;
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex)
    {
        dd($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When it fails(dd), the last result before dd should show you exactly which one is going bad.